# Is the set of functions $f$ in $C[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=f(1)$ a subspace of $C[-1,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Is the set of functions $f$ in $C[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=f(1)$ a subspace of $C[-1,1]$?

I understand that if $\forall x\in Dom(f)(f(-x)=f(x))$ is $true$ then the function would be even and the sum of two even functions is even therefore the first closure condition is fulfilled and the second too because the multiplication of a scalar times an even function is also an even function. But I don't manage to understand or prove how having just one value in the domain where $f(-x)=f(x)$ makes it even.

Comment: what do you mean 'one value in the domain'?  The domain is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Thoth, yes, but i'm given only one case of $f(x)$... maybe i lack some base knowledge here but how do i infer from $f(-1)=f(1)$ that $f(x)=f(-x)$ is also true $\forall x \in [-1,1]$?

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I understood now, I was reading the problem in a wrong way. I'm very sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same process which shows even functions are closed under addition will show 
$$
V = \left\{f\in C[-1,1] \mid f(-1) = f(1)\right\}
$$
is closed under addition.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are in $V$.  Then what is $(f+g)(-1)$?  What is $(f+g)(1)$?  Are they the same?

Similarly for scalar multiples.

Comment: but how do you know that $f(-x) = f(x)$ for the rest of the $x$ values in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I understood now, I was reading the problem in a wrong way. I'm very sorry, thanks.

Comment: @DavidCabrera: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ and $g$ be in $C[-1,1]$ such that $f(-1)=f(1)$ and $g(-1)=g(1)$ and let $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb{R}$. Then $$\alpha f(-1)+\beta g(-1)=\alpha f(1)+\beta g(1).$$ So $\alpha f+\beta g \in \left\{h\in C[-1,1] \mid h(-1) = h(1)\right\}$ which is thus a subspace.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I understood now, I was reading the problem in a wrong way. I'm very sorry, thanks.